# Package natbib Warning Submission in arXiv

Tags: citing, natbib, arxiv

While doing a submission a paper in arXiv, I got these two  problems

```
"LaTeX Warning: Reference `xxxx' on page xx undefined on input l
ine xxx.
"Package natbib Warning: Citation "xxxx"  on page xx undefined on input line ".
```

I have been doing a lot of solution I found it in net such as: 
I added `[numbers, comme square]` as options for `\usepackage{natbib}`
but it is the same problem. Besides, I add the fichier `00README.XXX` containing "nohypertex" but the problem persists. Does any one give me a solution for that please.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @layth: did you solve your problem?